# SSL Error on Heroku app

Tags: ssl, heroku, openssl, ssl-certificate

I cannot get ssl to work properly on my heroku app.
I have successfully add the crt key witch gives me:

```
Resolving trust chain... done
Updating SSL Endpoint aichi-7001.herokussl.com for mysite... done
Updated certificate details:
Common Name(s): mysite.com
                www.mysite.com

Expires At:     2013-11-03 23:59 UTC
Issuer:         /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Free SSL/CN=www.mysite.com
Starts At:      2013-08-05 00:00 UTC
Subject:        /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Free SSL/CN=www.mysite.com
SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.
```

but when i try to load the page on the browser, i get the following message:

```
This is probably not the site you are looking for!
You attempted to reach www.mysite.com.br, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.herokuapp.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of www.mysite.com.br.
You should not proceed, especially if you have never seen this warning before for this site.
```

Any ideias on where did I mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the domain www.mysite.com to your Heroku app like so:

```
$ heroku domains:add www.mysite.com

Added www.mysite.com to example... done
```